# To generalize a function that accesses multiple types of object (via function & array)

Tags: php, refactoring

I now have 2 functions to construct `html` to display, depending on data source; 1 is from `database`, the other is from `form` `post`.

```
function buildForm_newUser($user){
     $html_username = 'Username = ' . $_POST['username'];
     $html_location = 'location = ' . $_POST['location'];
     : // similar rows follow more than 20 times 
}

function buildForm_exsitingUser($user){
     $html_username = 'Username = ' . $user->get_property('username');
     $html_location = 'location = ' . $user->get_property('location');
     :
}
```

Is it possible to achieve these with only 1 function?

I tried to switch source object (i.e. `$user` and `$_POST` above) but then got stuck since the latter function uses function of the designated object, whereas the former doesn't. Also, because there are many rows that have to access either object, I like to declare newly generated variables ($html_* variables in the example above) at **only one location**. That said, I want something like this:

```
function buildForm($user){ // Number and type of argument can vary

     // Do something here to specify object type

     $html_username = 'Username = ' . // following here, either $_POST or $user->get_property to get 'username'
     $html_location = 'location = ' . // following here, either $_POST or $user->get_property to get 'location'
     :
}
```

Thanks.

(Also appreciate suggestion for better title...)

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly write in your question, those two functions are somewhat doing the same so you want to have one function instead.

Your motivation is good and you spotted a place for improvement right. How to do that? First of all, extract a new, third method:

```
function buildForm_array($array)
{
     $html_username = 'Username = ' . $array['username'];
     $html_location = 'location = ' . $array['location'];
     ... // similar rows follow more than 20 times 

}
```

Then use that third method inside the two existing methods:

```
function buildForm_newUser()
{
     buildForm_array($_POST);
}

function buildForm_exsitingUser($user)
{
     $array['username'] = $user->get_property('username');
     $array['location'] = $user->get_property('location');
     ...
     buildForm_array($array);
}
```

Depending how your actual code looks like, this can lead to different results (the example here is obviously not the end of the road), you could for example, create a `$user` object based on `$_POST` and then use it to generate the form by using the existing `buildForm_exsitingUser($user)` function.

That would be similar to using the new, third function but without creating it. So locate the patterns, and just reduce the duplicate code. Simplify.

This is always work in progress, so keep your code dynamic, change it.

Comment: +1 although your idea isn't simpler than what I ideally expected, it still simplifies something (in this case, the part that does job for final output can't be unified. Say it's like adopter pattern?). Just wait for a moment & see whatever other options might come up if any.

Answer (score 0):

What is calling this function? You could simply accept a username and userlocation as parameters...

Comment: + the other 20 parameters as written, so it's not that easy, but your idea is not wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read that part. But I think that it's not so ugly: a form constructor should just build a form, without caring what is the source of the data. Actually, I think it would be wrong to include some "functional" intelligence related code within your function!